# Update value used in Service on button click android

Tags: android

Hello I am using  a service to show some count. When the count incremented or decremented on button click i need to update the value in service. How to update a value in service after it started using button click.

Any help will be appeciable.

Answer (score 0):

You can store your values in Shared Preference and use these values in your service after updating the value

Comment: sorry this is not the way there also we need to use timer. I think i need to use bind service using IBinder

Comment: You can also do one thing from where u call the service intent you can set intent extra value in service and use it